# TeamCity not allowed access to git repo despide deploy key

Tags: github, teamcity

I have two private git repositories at `git@github.com:my-org/foo.git` and `git@github.com:my-org/bar.git`, which I want to build and deploy using TeamCity. To do this, I've [set up authentication using deploy keys](http://codemeyer.net/2014/10/27/teamcity-and-a-private-github-repo/) for both repos.

This works well for one of them (the first one I did it for), but the second one fails to fetch the sources with an authentication failure. From what I can see, I've done exactly the same steps on both repos and both build projects, but apparently there's something I'm missing.

The "Test Connection" button in the VCS root settings pane for the failing repo gives me "Connection successful", even though the build fails, but I can RDP into the build agent and reproduce the auth failure manually by running the same series of commands in powershell, as the user running the TeamCity service.

I've tried and re-tried this a number of times now, and I'm running out of ideas on what to try and how to troubleshoot.

Are there any things not mentioned in the [linked blog post](http://codemeyer.net/2014/10/27/teamcity-and-a-private-github-repo/) that I might have accidentally gotten right on one of the repos - names of things that need to line up, or anythings like that? What else would you suggest that I try/check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a different setting which differed between the two build projects: `VCS Checkout Mode`. It needs to be set to `Automatically on server` for the linked approach to work, and for the failing project it wasn't.

The main reason I didn't find it before is that it's not a setting on the VCS root itself (and thus the connection test works fine even when it's wrongly configured) but accessible under the build project settings, under `Version Control Settings`.